# How to perform a function to set a data automatically expired after creating data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, visual-studio-code

I am taking software engineering and I want to figure out how to perform the aforementioned thing.

My project runs Expressjs framework and MVC structure.

I'm using Visual Studio Code as a text editor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0z54.png)

My website is about Survey website, and I want to perform a function to set a survey automatically expired at a certain time after creating a survey.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCiAS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cREm.png)

---- This is the model schema about Survey in the models folder.

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

//create a model class
let surveyModel = mongoose.Schema({
  questionNum1: Number,
  questionNum2: Number,
  questionNum3: Number,
  questionType1: String, // True & False
  questionType2: String,
  questionType3: String,
  title: String, // title
  question1: String,
  question2: String,
  question3: String,
  tf: String, // ?? answer 
  creator: String, // user._id = req.user(log in)
  writer: String, // user.displayname 
  onOff: Boolean // ?? use of survey
},
{
  collection: "Survey"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Survey', surveyModel);
```

---- This is app.js in the config folder.

```
//installed 3rd party packages
let createError = require('http-errors');
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');

//modules for authentication
let session = require('express-session');
let passport = require('passport');
let passportLocal = require('passport-local');

//authentication objects
let localStrategy = passportLocal.Strategy;
// create a Visitor Model Instance
let visitorModel = require('../models/visitor');
let Visitor = visitorModel.Visitor;

//module for auth messaging and error management
let flash = require('connect-flash');

let indexRouter = require('../routes/index');
let usersRouter = require('../routes/users');
let surveyRouter = require('../routes/survey');

let app = express();

//database setup
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let DB = require('./db');

// point mongoose to the DB URI
mongoose.connect(DB.URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
let mongoDB = mongoose.connection; //alias

mongoDB.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection Error:'));
mongoDB.once('open', ()=>{
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB...');
});

mongoDB.once('connected', ()=>{
  console.log('MongoDB Connected');
});

mongoDB.on('disconnected', ()=>{
  console.log('MongoDB Disconnected');
});

mongoDB.on('reconnected', ()=>{
  console.log('MongoDB Reconnected');
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // express -e

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public'))); // add routes automatically
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../node_modules')));

//setup express session
let Auth = require('./auth');
app.use(session({
  secret: Auth.Secret,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false
}));

// initialize flash
app.use(flash());

// initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport visitor configuration

// impletment a User Authentication Strategy
passport.use(Visitor.createStrategy());

// serialize and deserialize the Visitor Info
passport.serializeUser(Visitor.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Visitor.deserializeUser());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/survey-list', surveyRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {title: 'Error'});
  //res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

---- These are modules to perform CRUD function for Survey data in the controllers' folder.

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let mongoose = require('mongoose');


let Survey = require('../models/survey');
let Title = require('../models/result');
const { disable } = require('debug');



/* GET Survey List page. READ */

module.exports.displaySurveyList = (req, res, next) => {
  
    Survey.find({creator: req.user._id},(err, surveyList) => {
        if(err){
            return console.error(err);
        }else{

            res.render('createSurvey/list', 
            {title: 'Create Survey', 
            SurveyList: surveyList, 
            displayName: req.user ? req.user.displayName : '',});
        }
    });
    
}



module.exports.postSurveyList = (req, res, next) => 
{
    let newTitle = Title({
       "title": req.body.title,
       "creator": req.user._id, 
       "writer" : req.user.displayName,
       "onOff" : true
    });

    Title.create(newTitle, (err, Title) => {
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.end(err);
      }else{
          console.log('save');
          res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
}



module.exports.displayAddPage = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('createSurvey/add', {
        title: 'Add List',
        displayName: req.user ? req.user.displayName : ''});
}



module.exports.processingAddPage = (req, res, next) => 
{
    let newSurvey = Survey({
       "questionNum1": 1,
       "questionNum2": 2,
       "questionNum3": 3,
       "question1" : req.body.question,
       "question2" : req.body.question2,
       "question3" : req.body.question3,
       "questionType1" : req.body.questionType,
       "questionType2" : req.body.questionType2,
       "questionType3" : req.body.questionType3,
       "title" : req.body.title,
       "creator": req.user._id, 
       "writer" : req.user.displayName,
       "onOff" : true
    });

    Survey.create(newSurvey, (err, Survey) => {
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.end(err);
      }else{
          // refresh the book list
          res.redirect('/survey-list');
      }
    });
}


module.exports.displayEditPage = (req, res, next) => 
{
    let id = req.params.id;

    Survey.findById(id, (err, surveyToEdit) => {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.end(err);
       }else{
           if(req.user.displayName == surveyToEdit.writer){
           //show the edit view          
           res.render('createSurvey/edit', {
               title: 'Edit Question', 
               survey: surveyToEdit,
               displayName: req.user ? req.user.displayName : ''})
           }
       }
    });

}


module.exports.processingEditPage = (req, res, next) => 
{
    let id = req.params.id;

    let updatedServey = Survey({
        "_id": id,
        "questionNum1": 1,
        "questionNum2": 2,
       "questionNum3": 3,
       "question1" : req.body.question1,
       "question2" : req.body.question2,
       "question3" : req.body.question3,
       "questionType1" : req.body.questionType,
       "questionType2" : req.body.questionType2,
       "questionType3" : req.body.questionType3,
       "title" : req.body.title,

    });

    Survey.updateOne({_id: id}, updatedServey, (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.end(err);
        }else{
            // refresh the user list
            res.redirect('/survey-list');
        }
    });
}


module.exports.performDeletion = (req, res, next) => 
{
    let id = req.params.id;

    Survey.remove({_id: id}, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.end(err);
    }else{
        // refresh the user list
        res.redirect('/survey-list');
    }
    });

}


module.exports.displaySettingPage = (req, res, next) => 
{
    let id = req.params.id;

    Survey.findById(id, (err, surveyToSetting) => {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.end(err);
       }else{
           //show the edit view
           if(req.user.displayName == surveyToSetting.writer){
           res.render('createSurvey/setting', {
               title: 'Edit Question', 
               setting: surveyToSetting,
               displayName: req.user ? req.user.displayName : ''})
           }
       }
    });

}


module.exports.processingSettingPage = (req, res, next) => 
{
    let id = req.params.id;

    let updatedServey = Survey({
        "_id": id,
        "onOff" : req.body.onAndOff
    });

    Survey.updateOne({_id: id}, updatedServey, (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.end(err);
        }else{
            // refresh the user list
            res.redirect('/survey-list');
        }
    });
}
```

I was advised that

1. I need to have an expiration date field in the survey model
2. And then I need to use an if statement in the view or a conditional query on
   the controller
3. also need an Active field in the survey model.

But, I still have no ideas on how to precisely do it.

Is there anyone who can help?
Thank you

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Seems all you need is an expire date calculated when you create it and add to your schema. Then when you query for that object and it is expired show a different view to user